# This webpage is not available ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: errors

I have a website that runs wordpress.

I'm new to this so I was messing with the settings to see what they do.

My domain name was www.example.com and there was a setting that was allowing me to change it.

This is the link it led me to https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

After changing it to www.example1.com I no longer have access to my admin page.

www.example.com works but it lost all the CSS elements, when I try to add the wp-login at the end it redirects me to www.example1.com and prompts me with that error.

Does anyone know how to fix that or revert these changes? I only have access to the server, not the host, so I cannot reinstall wordpress for this domain.

It keeps redirecting me to www.example1.com, how can I stop that?

Answer (score 1):

Those settings are stored in the `wp_options` table in the database.

If you can access the database with PHPMyAdmin
Location the `wp_options` table and find the records with the `option_name` of `home` and `siteurl` and change it back to the correct url.

Your host may also be willing to help with this.

Answer (score 0):

first export you database in you system as db.sql after that open it and please do following thing:-

1. find www.example.com
2. replace it with www.example1.com.
3. and re import it.

After this admin would work and if page url dont work, please change the permalinks settings.

Thanks :)